# Sync sudo anthority to all nodes

Tags: apt, sudo, cluster, batch-jobs, cluster-ssh

I want to submit a task that is interpreted by `/bin/csh`, which only exists in master node. And I have no root permission but only sudo, which is limited in master node. So I can't use `sudo apt install csh` in each calculation node.

How to handle the case?

Answer (score 0):

You have two good options:

1. Ask your cluster sysadmins to install `csh` on the compute nodes for you,

or

2. rewrite the `csh` script in `sh` or `bash`. or maybe `ksh` or `zsh` if they're installed on the compute nodes.  Or `perl` or `python`.

I recommend a rewrite, there's really no good reason to be writing scripts in `csh`.

BTW, see [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

`csh` was a good user-friendly interactive shell when it was first written in 1978, and maintained that role in the 80s and into the early 90s (although `ksh`, `bash`, and `zsh` and others have far surpassed it now) but was always a terrible, buggy scripting language.

The modern incarnation, `tcsh` (which is probably what you're using), fixes some but not all of `csh`'s bugs.  It's still not a good language for scripts.